# Dead Money DLC and main story

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I just bought Dead Money DLC, during Steam sales, but I haven't finished Fallout: New Vegas yet; I played about 25 hours and probably I am just in the middle of the story.

What does it mean? Is Dead Money DLC playable only after Fallout: New Vegas end or could/should I access its content before?

Comment: I can't give a definitive answer, but every Fallout 3 DLC with the exception of Broken Steel was a completely unrelated storyline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be at least on level 20 and you can access it before the end of the main story. More details (and spoilers): http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Money

EDIT: [Today's (July 6th 2011) update](http://store.steampowered.com/news/5802/) fixed the fact that one could not engage on DLC's quests after main story ending.

> New feature: system save is
>   automatically created prior to endgame
>   sequence. After credits, user is
>   prompted to load save game. This will
>   allow single save players to play DLC
>   without creating a new game.

Comment: I'd add that you **must** start it before the end of the main story. I'm not sure you CAN access it afterwards.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy Good point! I got that feeling reading the wiki as well...

Comment: It's not possible to play after the end of the main story, so every Fallout: New Vegas DLC released until now must be played before the end of the main story. Also of note is that you can begin playing before level 20, but it's not recommended due to the difficulty of the DLC.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy @Wilerson From now on it will be possible to play DLC after end of the main story, acording to the newest update of the game. The answer was modified adding that information.

Comment: @weslei: Yea they did that with F3 as well. Still, there never seems like any point once the credits have rolled.

Answer (score 1):

Once you install the DLC, you will detect a new radio signal and can travel to the location NE of Nelson, where you get the option to travel to the DLC location.  There is no level requirement but a high level is suggested.  You can get the radio signal as soon as you step into the Mojave.

Keep in mind coming back will not be easy so be prepared to spend some time way from the main quest.